# error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier when iterating in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

My code keeps generating the error:
error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier when iterating in C

This is the section it is complaining about specifically:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (gamesToPlay); i++)
{
    printf("You are now playing game %d\n", i);
}
```

Did I do something wrong? I'm compiling using VS 2010 with a .c file.

Comment: You are trying to write C++ in C.

Comment: @bmargulies More like trying to write C99 in C89.

Comment: You need to get a real C compiler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 only supports C89, not C99. In C89, a variable must be declared in the beginning of a block like this:

```
void foo(void)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < gamesToPlay; i++)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that even in c89, `void foo(void) { /* ... */ }` is recommended over `void foo() { /* ... */ }`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `i` outside the `for`

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < (gamesToPlay); i++)
{
    printf("You are now playing game %d\n", i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First expression in a `for` statement can be a declaration which was introduced in C99. VS 2010 doesn't support C99 and that's why you are getting this error. Declare `i` in the beginning of block as in C89

```
int i;
...

for (i = 0; i < (gamesToPlay); i++)
{
    printf("You are now playing game %d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Only 2013, I believe :-(. And support still isn't full, but that is a good progress.